# What is preventing me from generating a graph in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am currently trying to plot a graph using the following script.

```
plot1 <- ggplot(lab4.csv , aes( data_type, num_people))
plot1 + theme( legend.position = "none" )
```

**I am getting this error:**

> plot1 + theme( legend.position = "none" )
> Error: object 'plot1' not found

I am new to R and am not sure what I am overlooking here.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Add a `;` between your two commands, or put the second command on a new line.  (Although note that you haven't included any kind of `geom_` instruction to define what kind of plot you want.)

Comment: @andrew_reece Also data must be loaded first.

Comment: @andrew_reece Thanks for the response. I've added the semicolon to break up the two commands now. Where is the proper placement for geom_boxplot()?

Comment: @Duck By load do you mean have the data imported into RStudio? I currently have the data in the top left pane of my workspace.

Comment: Please have a look at [ask] and then post a [mcve].

Comment: The error message tells you that object `plot1` does not exist. That means that your previous line of code did not run correctly. Does object `lab4,csv` exist? Or is that a file on your PC which has to be loaded (e.g. with `read.csv`)? Do the columns  `data_type` and `num_people` exist in your data? They are mapped to respectively the x and y axis: are they numeric?

Comment: Run the first line of your code separately and ensure that `plot1` is created in your environment.  If it is, then "run" `plot1` in your console and you should at least see an empty plot (as you have not specified a geom for drawing).  I would suggest to create the plot via adding geoms, etc via the general structure: `ggplot(...) + geom_*(...) + theme(...) + ...`.   Saving to a separate object is not required, but often useful if you're doing something else with it later.